Showing that an estimator is consistent and asymptotically normal
I have the following exercise and i am kind of stuck.
Consider a random sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ of $n$ observations from a $\operatorname{POISS}(\mu)$-distribution. Use $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{X_1+\cdots+X_n}$ to estimate the unknown probability $P\left(X_1=0\right)=e^{-\mu}$. You may use the well-known result: $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n}\left(n \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+1\right)=0$

Show that the estimator is consistent
Show that the estimator is asymptotically normal

I know that ${X_1+\cdots+X_n}$ converges in probabilty to $n\mu$ by use of WLLN, and I know $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx} = e^{-x}$ but I don't know how to combine these things using properties of convergence in probability.

Are you sure about your statement for WLLN?

You have a lot of extra information here arising from the Poisson assumption.  In particular, because $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ has a Poisson distribution with mean and variance $n\mu,$ you can find high-probability upper and lower bounds to the value of $(1-1/n)^{S_n}$ for the consistency demonstration.

Although $\left( 1 - \frac1n\right)^{X_1+\cdots+X_n}$ is the unique best unbiased estimator of $e^{-\mu},$ when the sample size $n$ is small you're better off using the MLE than an unbiased estimator. The MLE in this case is $e^{-(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n}.$ To see why, start by considering what happens when $n=1.$ (Recall that $0^0=1$ and $0^x=0$ when $x>0. \qquad$

To say that $X_1+\cdots + X_n$ converges in probability to $n\lambda$ as $n\to\infty$ is a bit odd when you consider that a limit as $n$ approaches something should be a quantity that does not depend on $n.$ But $(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n \to\lambda$ in probability as $n\to\infty. \qquad$

If it is expected that you will use the fact that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n \left(n \ln \left(1-\frac1n \right)+1\right)=0,$$ then I won't be surprised if thinking about $$\lim _{n \to \infty} \sqrt n \left(n \overline X_n \ln \left(1-\frac1n \right)+1\right)=0,$$ is involved, where $\overline X_n= (X_1+\cdots +X_n)/n. \qquad$

Yes, thank you for your answer!
